# Different JsonSerializerSettings for different values in list

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, .net-core-2.2

I am using this setting to serialize a list of objects in **dotnet core 2.2**:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    DateFormatString = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"
}
```

The problem is I want it to serialize and deserialize DateTimes with "MM/dd/yyyy" if DateTimes time equals to 0 and I found no dynamic way to do it in the same list with both values (DateTimes with different times, 0 or not 0)

Comment: Create your own `JsonConverter`. And there's no reason to stuck in 2.2 and not move to 3.1.

Comment: I was going to inherit JsonConvertor. The purpose of this question is to use any potential existing feature, which is superior to inheritance. But it seems a derived class is the only way.
About dotnet 2.2: we are considering the move directly to dotnet 5. Yet I am not the one deciding the time.

Comment: .NET 5 (stable one) is pretty far in future, and it's not good idea, as for me. For me is better to move on 3.1 (it's LTS, stable, here, and now) and then to .NET 6 because .NET 5 is transition build and will not include all desired features. [2.2 is outdated](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core), and may be vulnerable. Btw, yes, the `JsonConverter` is the only way to achieve custom deserealization behavior.

Comment: Also [.NET 6 will be LTS](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/05/19/net-5-preview-4.aspx?m=1), not .NET 5

Comment: It's correct and thanks for your suggestion. Still lets stick to the point of the question. Will a move, ease the solution of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own json converter for for this.

```
public class DateTimeStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    // allowable DateTime formats - update as required
    List<string> DateFormats => new List<string> { "MM/dd/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt" };

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dateStr = (string)reader.Value;
        DateTime date;
        foreach (string format in DateFormats)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
            {
                return date;
            }
        }

        throw new JsonException($"{dateStr} as not a valid date string.");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(value.ToString());
        // Time value of DateTime.Today is always "00:00:00"
        if (date.TimeOfDay == DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        }
        else
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"));
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
    }
}
```

You could improve this by changing `DateFormats` to public List and pass through valid DateTime formats when initializing `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Then you can apply the settings like this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None;
settings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeStringConverter());

// deserialize
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(json, settings);

// serialize
var serializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, settings);
```

<sup>This was inspired by the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318713/supporting-multiple-custom-datetime-formats-when-deserializing-with-json-net)</sup>

Comment: This will cover part of my requirements. But some of my objects are anonymous, or Dictionaries of type <string, object>. Is there anything I could do for them? They are the most important part of serialization.

Comment: @FarhadGh Check the accepted answer here: [Supporting multiple custom DateTime formats when deserializing with Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51318713/supporting-multiple-custom-datetime-formats-when-deserializing-with-json-net)

Comment: Your link pointed me to real solution. I will update what worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @FarhadGh I have updated my answer to better match your requirements and have also implemented Serialize (didn't have time to update answer yesterday).